# Azk with phpmyadmin

Tags: docker, azk

I'm using azk with Ruby on Rails and Mysql, it works fine.
I'd like to add a third container with phpmyadmin, to easily browse and manage the database.
Any idea how this could be done? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from the azk core team and I've just made an example `Azkfile.js` showing how you can use the image mentioned by @h3nrik.

```
systems({
  app: {
    // ...
  },
  mysql: {
    // ...
    ports: {
      // exports global variables
      data: "3306/tcp",
    },
    envs: {
      // set instances variables
      MYSQL_USER     : "azk",
      MYSQL_PASS     : "azk",
      MYSQL_DATABASE : "#{system.name}_development",
      PMA_URI: "#{system.name}.#{azk.default_domain}",
    },
    export_envs:{
      MYSQL_USERNAME: "#{envs.MYSQL_USER}",
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "#{envs.MYSQL_PASS}",
      MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR: "#{net.host}",
      MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT: "#{net.port.data}",
      DATABASE_URL: "mysql2://#{envs.MYSQL_USER}:#{envs.MYSQL_PASS}@#{net.host}:#{net.port.data}/${envs.MYSQL_DATABASE}",
    },
  },
  "phpmyadmin": {
    depends: ["mysql"],
    image: { docker: "corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin" },
    wait: {"retry": 20, "timeout": 1000},
    scalable: {"default": 0, limit: 1},
    http: {
      // phpmyadmin.dev.azk.io
      domains: [ "#{system.name}.#{azk.default_domain}" ]
    },
    ports: {
      // exports global variables
      http: "80/tcp",
    },
    envs: {
      PMA_USERNAME: "azk",
      PMA_PASSWORD: "azk",
      PMA_URI: "#{system.name}.#{azk.default_domain}",
    },
  },
})
```

After you add the above info into your `Azkfile.js`, just run the command below:

```
azk start phpmyadmin --open
```

Any other issue, just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try for instance [this](https://github.com/corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin) container? You can find a lot `phpmyadmin` containers on github and docker hub.